# Laravel 5.2. Checking logged user are the owner of the page and provide authentication for action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have developed a web application similar with facebook. User can create a page and perform action inside their page. But now i facing a problems is how can i store the page id when user posting status. Because i am using Laravel RESTful Resource to create controller. If i want to passing page id through link it does not allow because the route is defined as 
`Route::resource('posts','PostController');`

In my controller i having function for storing page status which is

```
public function storePost(Request $request)
```

if i change to

```
Route::resource('posts/{id}','PostController@storePost');
```

and

```
 public function storePost(Request $request,$pageId)
```

it will occurs error.

Can i know is there any way can passing the page id other than GET function?

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to describe actual problem and post appropriate code.

Comment: Is it possible to just include the `page_id` in the post data?

Comment: Since Laravel 5.2 Implicit controller route deprected, use explicit route registration in your routes file.